# Hapi,js - Proper way to include a plugin inside a plugin

Tags: hapi.js

I have this Hapi.js server that requires 2 endpoints to do Basic auth(using the hapi-auth-basic module). Each endpoints logic for checking the "username/password" is different, so i've broken these 2 things into their own plugins.

Currently this is how i am registering the the plugins:

```js
...

server.register([Basic,
...
    require('./auth/register-device'),
    require('./auth/sender'),
...
], (err) => {
 ....
```

While this works, i have to make sure that the Basic plugin is also being registered.

I tried to register the Basic plugin in my plugins register method here(which i've removed and moved to the above file):

https://github.com/salty-pig/Salty-Pig/blob/master/auth/sender.js#L29 , but when i did that for both plugins, i got the error that the Basic plugin was already registered.

I guess i'm wondering what the best practice here should be.  In my case, this works since i'm not distributing these "auth" plugins.

Question 2 would be: If i had a plugin that i wanted to make into a npm module, that needed to include another plugin, what are the best practices for that.

thanks

Comment: Not sure what this means, 'i have to make sure that the Basic plugin is also being registered'. You're trying to make a circular dependency between Basic and Sender, aren't you?

Comment: i don't think so.  The Sender plugin does need the Basic plugin to work,  but the Basic plugin doesn't need the Sender plugin.   What i meant was, for the sender and register-device plugins to work, i need to register the Basic plugin first,  I tried registering the Basic plugin inside each of those other plugins, but thats when i got the error about the Basic plugin already being registered

Comment: Would be interesting to know how this should be handled properly, too. My guess is that the behaviour is fine-tuned with `once` option [here](http://hapijs.com/api#serverregisterplugins-options-callback), `once` and `multiple` options [here](http://hapijs.com/api#plugins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing a plugin that depends on other plugins, you could use the [Hapi `server.dependency` API](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#serverdependencydependencies-after):

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
  server.dependency('hapi-auth-basic', function(server, next) {
    server.register([
      // register plugins that depend on hapi-auth-basic here
    ], (err) => {
    });
  });

  next();
};
```

You can supply `server.dependency` with an array to specify multiple dependencies.